# Python: Mocking a module that's being used by a module I'm testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to mock a certain module in order to test a piece of code that is using the module.

That is to say, I have a module `my_module` which I'd like to test. `my_module` imports an external module `real_thing` and calls `real_thing.compute_something()`:

```
#my_module
import real_thing
def my_function():
    return real_thing.compute_something()
```

I need to mock `real_thing` so that in a test it will behave like `fake_thing`, a module that I've created:

```
#fake_thing
def compute_something():
    return fake_value
```

The test calls `my_module.my_function()` which calls `real_thing.compute_something()`:

```
#test_my_module
import my_module
def test_my_function():
    assert_something(my_module.my_function())
```

What should I add to the test code so that `my_function()` will call `fake_thing.compute_something()` within the test instead of `real_thing.compute_something()`?

I was trying to figure out how to do so with [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html), but I haven't.

Comment: How about putting `import fake_thing as real_thing` at the top of your test file?

Comment: I always find the easiest way to mock a module is to point directly at it, and shout, "Ha ha, you're a module!"

Comment: @David: This doesn't solve it. The test executes `my_module.my_function()` and `my_module` doesn't know it was called from a test. `my_module` imports `real_thing` and therefore `real_thing.compute_something()` will be executed, no matter what modules are actually imported in the test module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply that no ? Hack the sys.modules

```
#fake_thing.py
def compute_something():
    return 'fake_value'

#real_thing.py
def compute_something():
    return 'real_value'

#my_module.py
import real_thing
def my_function():
    return real_thing.compute_something()

#test_my_module.py
import sys

def test_my_function():
    import fake_thing
    sys.modules['real_thing'] = fake_thing
    import my_module
    print my_module.my_function()

test_my_function()
```

Outputs : 'fake_value'

Comment: The idea behind that is once you squat the module name, python reuses the same one without reloading it.

Comment: I've tested it and it doesn't work. `my_module.my_function()` still doesn't return the fake value; it calls `real_thing.calculate_something()` and hence returns the real value.

Comment: be *sure* you import my_module *after* doing the sys.modules trick otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have explicited my test case so you can reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/

```
>>> from mockito import *
>>> dog = mock()
>>> when(dog).bark().thenReturn("wuff")
>>> dog.bark()
'wuff'
```

http://technogeek.org/python-module.html - how to replace ,load module dynamically

Comment: Your answer as it is doesn't help me because in my question there's one more level of indirection: Let's say `dog.bark()` calls `dog.inhale()` and I want to mock `dog.inhale()` so that in the test, when calling `dog.bark()`, what would be called is my fake `dog.inhale()` instead of the real `dog.inhale()`. How can that be done?

Comment: You are right, I added link to Dynamic Module Loading in Python